# array.remove seems to skip elements for an unknown reason

Tags: arrays, swift

Somehow it seems that the `array.remove` looks to do weird things. Here is the code:

```
var test = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven"
var testarray = test.components(separatedBy: " ")
for i in 0..<4{
    testarray.remove(at: i)
}
print(testarray)
```

The code above should have given:

> ["four", "five", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]

because it should have removed the value from 0 to 4th but instead it skips and only deletes the even numbers.

> ["one", "three", "five", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]

Comment: Print the value of `testarray` and `i` inside the start and end of the loop. It will be obvious.

Comment: this is what i got 0
one
1
three
2
five
3
seven somehow 0(which is the first in array ) is one but 0 . should be zero

Comment: Okay, so `i` is `0`, you remove `four`, `i` is `1`, which makes `seven` the next element - skipping `five`, because it's now at `0` :/. Instead, loop until the array length is `0`

Comment: The problem is that you need to reverse your indices when removing your elements. `for i in stride(from: 3, through: 0, by: -1) {`. Btw much easier to use `removeFirst(4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you start with an array looking something like...

```
["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

When `i` is `0`, `"zero"` will be removed, leaving you with an array of...

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

When `i` is `1`, `"two"` will be removed, leaving you with an array of...

```
["one", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

So and so forth.  This occurs because you keep moving the index.

So, how could you remove the first 4 elements?

Well, you could just remove element `0` on each iteration, but that's boring.

You could do something like...

```
let prefix = testarray[0..<4]
// ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]
```

or

```
let sufix = testarray[5..<testarray.count]
// ["five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

or

```
let remaining = testarray[5...]
// ["five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

or

```
testarray.removeSubrange(0..<4)
// ["four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

or

```
testarray.removeFirst(4)
// ["four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

or

```
testarray.dropFirst(4)
// ["four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"]
```

which probably one of the safer methods, as it will allow you to "drop" more elements then exist without failure

... depending on your needs and preferences

Comment: why not simply `testarray[5...]` note that this might crash your app if you don't check the array count

Comment: @LeoDabus I'll add it to the list

Comment: Most important is to tell OP to always remove them in reverse order

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't know, you could use the same loop, but always remove element `0` :/

Comment: @LeoDabus All the examples "work" in one way or another, based on the available information from the user, it would, personally, be the one I might use, but since the "reason" is out of context, I'll leave it to the OP to decide which best meets their needs

Comment: @LeoDabus Really, because it failed in my (playground) test *"Fatal error: Can't remove more items from a collection than it has"*

Comment: my bad that's a mutating method behaves differently from dropFirst(n)

Comment: better to use `removeFirst(min(testarray.count,4))`

Answer (score 1):

Each time you perform a removal, the indices of array elements change. Initially, your array contains zero, one, two, three, ....

After removing the 0th element ("zero"), it contains one, two, three, ....

At this point, removing element 1 will remove "two". Your output is completely expected based on the code that you have written.

Comment: @javaperson try `for i in stride(from: 3, through: 0, by: -1) {` but as I said much better to use `testarray.removeFirst(4)`